# Is map[string]interface{} faster that map[string]string in golang? or are "strconv" functions too slow?

Tags: dictionary, interface, go

I'm making a url fetcher in golang. I'm new to golang and didn't know about **interace{}** type earlier and was hence using `map[string]string` for my **args_hash{}** (a general hash to pass arguments to my fetcher e.g.`time`,`date`,`site-path` etc). However, I learned later about `interface{}` type and changed my `map` to `map[string]interface{}`.

Various functions inside my fetcher use `args_hash{}`. Earlier, I had to convert the args that were supposed to be integers (but passed as **string** due to limitations of `map[string]string)` to integers using `strconv.Atoi()` and `stuff`. 
e.g.

```
func my_def(args_hash{} map[string]string){
    url_count := strconv.Atoi(args_hash["url_count"])
   // ... use url count
    .
    .
   // ......successful url count calculated
   args_hash["success_url_count"] = strconv.Itoa(success_count)
}
```

My methods did this several times earlier and also passed this modified `args_hash{}` between them several times.

But since now I've shifted to using

```
args_hash map[string]interface{}
```

I don't do this anymore.

With `map[string]string`, the time taken to fetch 10 particular urls was around 23 sec, however with `map[string]interface{}` this has reduced to nearly half (around 12-13 sec).

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Waiting for and downloading the HTTP response is the slow part. Unless you are doing something stupid the variation in measured times would be because of that. The type you use will be the least of your concern. Also, `string` and `interface{}` are not interchangeable, as in "which one should I use". You use `string`s for strings, and `interface{}` when the type is variable or unknown.

Comment: I too thought that waiting for http response,writing to databases,etc should've taken major time. But I'm pretty sure, that with this single change, the time difference is this big. I've no idea why that's happening though?

Comment: Well, we need to see some actual code to answer that. It could be anything from a bug in Go to a `time.Sleep()` gone horribly wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you might be coming from a dynamic language — like `JavaScript` or `Perl` — which lack support for "structures" (in the `C`-language sense, for instance) and so you're trying to use a map (what you call "a hash") instead of a Go `struct`, and passing around pointer to the instance of a struct.

So I'd rework your code like this:

```
type FetcherArgs struct {
    OkUrlCount int
    UrlCount int
    FooBar string
    // ... and so on
}

func my_def(args *FetcherArgs) {
    args.OkUrlCount += 1
    // ...
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", args.UrlCount)
    // ...
}

var args = FetchArgs{UrlCount: 42, FooBar: "Life, the Universe and Everything"}
my_def(&args)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the rework, it did give me a new perspective into things. But I think I'll stick with maps. I primarily use both 'C' and 'python' and think that maps/hash would be a better choice here, as they'll be easy to use and I can dynamically add fields to them anytime I want from anywhere.(AFAIK this can't be done with a structure? Please let me know if it can be. I would be grateful.)

Comment: @nomad, to the last question -- no, you cant. As to your other points, I don't really see how they make things easier: whenever you add a new pair to your map you have to modify other bits of the code which *use* the new key and its value. Now try to explain how this is really different from adding yet another field to a struct -- that you save adding exactly one line of source code? But you get type checking in return. I think this is overwhelmingly better than your imaginary saves on editing.

Comment: @nomad, IOW, maps are really useful when pairs they contain have a property of being *uniform,* and that clearly does not look like your case as you're effectively doing a key-based hardcoded type switching in your code.

Comment: ok, if you strongly insist, I'll try it out. thanks. Btw, will this make things faster? I mean passing structure pointers instead of maps, is the former faster?

Comment: @nomad Yes, structures are faster. Passing a pointer is still the same speed but access to members is faster since there is no hastable involved and since there is no type conversion.

Comment: @nomad - a structure is a better way to go. it organises things, fixes the types of things, and makes the code readable and maintainable. the map is flexible, but drops type safety and all the other good stuff

Comment: @sje397, moreover, the perceived flexibility of a map (it allows iteration over all its elements) can be compensated in Go by reflection -- for instance, Go has no problems serializing instances of arbitrary structs to JSON or XML, and back.